# Accesing youtube data from Android Service using Google API Java Client for Youtube on Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-service, google-api-java-client, android-youtube-api

I've searched a bunch online for any info about how to use the Google API Java Client Youtube related APIs for Android from within an Android service but haven't found any info yet...

I'm already using the APIs in my first Android app to access youtube data but it is all from within Activities.

I'm trying to understand if and how I could do the same from an Android service since I'm trying to write an Android service to fetch youtube search / playlist / other data in the background. I don't need to display it, just store the info in my DB from within my service.
Can anyone point me to info on this ?

I'm new to Android, Google APIs, Auth, web-services access etc (this is my first app & first time doing all of this)....am still going though the Google API Java Client Android Java docs to see if I can find anything there

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [UploadsService in YouTube Direct Lite for Android project](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android/blob/master/src/com/google/ytdl/UploadService.java).

Comment: thanks Ibrahim ! Looking at that & some more sample code using the client API, it's more clear now that many/most of the client APIs are not tied to Activities though they're generally used from within Activities.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would use an Asynctask within the Android Service and do the checking. Once You are ready with the data , you could save this to the Android DB , ie ( Android Offers SQLite Database Storage ) .

In your activity , you could simply check the database and update your activity accordingly .

You will need understand the following Topics

```
Android Services ( bound and unbound ) 
SQLite Db ( http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html )
AsyncTasks or Use Google Volley ..
```